# Reading CSV data from a file into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, function, csv, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary from a CSV file. The first column of the csv file contains unique keys and the second column contains values. Each row of the csv file represents a unique key, value pair within the dictionary. I tried to use the csv.DictReader and csv.DictWriter classes, but I could only figure out how to generate a new dictionary for each column. I want one dictionary. Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
def read_data(file_name):
    data = {}
    with open(file_name, "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')
        number_columns = len(next(reader))
        for d in range (number_columns):
            column_data, column_name = read_column(file_name, d)
            data[column_name] = column_data
    return data
```

My data: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnTZu.png)
My expected result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlUxf.png)

Comment: **Do not use images** for textual data. Copy and paste the example data and expected output as text into your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having a 2D table for you data instead of key-value pairs, you can use the pandas module and in the module is useful function called `to_dict()` that converts a CSV to a dictionary. So this is how an example would look like:

```
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',') #<---- the sep argument does the same thing as the delimiter argument, it is short for separator

random_dict = pd.to_dict(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) `DictReader`:

```
with open(file_name) as csv_file:
    dictR = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    data = {hdr: [] for hdr in dictR.fieldnames}
    for row in dictR:
        for field in row:
            data[field].append(row[field])
```

Build initial `data` `dict` using the field names fetched from the `DictReader`. Then iterate over rows and fields in row. For each field append the field value to the list corresponding to the field name in the `data` `dict`.